# Execute a statement after logging in to SSH

Tags: bash, shell, ssh

I am writing a script in which i have to execute a set of statments after logging in via SSH. So i am using this command

```
ssh -t  user@adf-svc-1001.do.e1.bboo.com $COMMAND "&& exec bash -l"
```

Now this works if i give `COMMAND` as any single line statement such as `ls` or `mkdir`, but its not working if i put the following in `COMMAND`

```
COMMAND= "if [ $B==$A ]
             then
             echo 'ERROR'
          fi "
```

I tried putting `\` at the end of each line,changed the indentation,put it into a single line but its throwing error

```
fi : command not found
syntax error near unexpected token `&&'
```

Comment: Try putting `;` before `then` and `fi`statements. `COMMAND= "if [ $B==$A ]; then echo 'ERROR';fi "`

Comment: sorry updated my comment.

Comment: The best advice for complex operation on the remote-host is the write a script and save it on the remote host, then you can simply call the script by `ssh you@somehost 'bash scriptname'`. (or make it executable on the remote host and you can drop `bash`)

Comment: @Kadir same result even after the updated comment.

Comment: You can write a multi-line ssh command. Hierarchically speaking, the command(s) to be run on the remote machine will be wrapped in single-inverted commas and the logic-internal parameters will be in double inverted commas.

Comment: Also, have you considered dumping all of this in a shell file, pushing the shell file to the target and using ssh only to run that `/bin/bash /remote/path/to/your/script.sh`?

Comment: `COMMAND="if [ $B==$A ]; then echo 'ERROR'; fi;"` this one runs successfully on my test server. One space at the end. @Diffy

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin yes i can do that of course. But since it is a 10-15 line script, i didnt want to put it on the remote server. Just wanted to keep it in one file.

Comment: @Kadir is this whole if else in one line only? And where will that 1 space come?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is the ssh statement itself. ssh command should be run like:

```
ssh -t user@adf-svc-1001.do.e1.bboo.com $COMMAND && exec bash -l
```

Second one is that `COMMAND` variable should be assigned as one line like:

```
COMMAND="if [ $B==$A ]; then echo 'ERROR'; fi;"
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I see no reason to put the conditional construct in a subshell.

Comment: This is working fine for me. I think i was missing the semicolons after `echo` and `fi`.

Comment: @4ae1e1 You are right. Subshell is needless as i invoked without double quotes.

Comment: `... $COMMAND && exec bash -l` This runs the `exec bash` part on the local server, instead of the remote server.